# Synchronous controller with Task.Factory.StartNew versus Asynchronous controller in MVC 4 versus Service Broker Activation

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have a project running in MVC 4 on a .Net 4.0 VS2010 environment. I need to have a long running sql task handled without making the user wait on the front end for that long. 
The MVC 4 web application calls the business layer which calls a data layer method which Executes the SP using the code snippet as below.

```
public DataSet ExecuteSP()
{

        dbc = database.GetStoredProcCommand('long_running_sp');
        dbc.CommandTimeout = 300;

        foreach (SPParams p in spParams)
        {
            dbc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(p.ParamName, p.ParamValue));
        }

        DataSet ds = _database.ExecuteDataSet(dbc);

        return ds;
}
```

The two options I tried were using a Synchronous controller which obviously did not work, and then the other was using an AsyncController. I found out that both options hanged my website after the call to the stored procedure was made in the data layer. Then I introduced the Task.Factory.StartNew method in my AsyncController. It worked. Then I went and applied the same in my Synchronous controller and it worked there too.

Now the question is: If all I need to apply was Task.Factory.StartNew, then why bother with using an AsyncController? Or better still why not ditch the Task.Factory.StartNew altogether and just go with [Service Broker Activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617.aspx)

What is the better option here?

Comment: If you need to return a recordset then I doubt Service Broker will be of much help here.

Comment: No I don't. Its a fire and forget situation. There will be another polling operation running on the website to check for the job being flagged as finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between an AsyncController and a normal controller is that you can handle more requests at the same time.

The situation you have is a fire-and-forget situation. The AsyncController is more suited for situations where you have a long request (usually network or I/O-bound). While from the clients-perspective you won't notice any difference in response time, there is a difference on the server level.

If you use a synchronous controller, it will block the thread. IIS has a limited amount of threads available in the threadpool. If you block threads, it's possible that IIS runs out of threads. The result will be that other threads are queued because you have to many blocked threads. With an async controller, you free up these threads while they are not doing anything, so they can service other requests.

So, from a single user perspective, the response time will be the same, since you still have to wait for the response. From a multi-user perspective the total response time will be better, since you can serve more users at the same time.

As said earlier, if you're executing a fire-and-forget, there's no reason to use an async controller, since what you want is just to fire the query and return a result to the user. The method you're applying is the correct one for this situation.

If you need to return the result to the user, it's better to use an async controller, since this will free up the waiting thread. (that is if it's network or IO-bound, because if it's CPU-bound there's no gain at all)